# How to get information about BIOS from terminal?

Tags: command-line, bios

I want to get BIOS information and print information about all structures.

How to get via command-line?

Comment: What do you mean with entry points? The boot order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man biosdecode`:

```
NAME
       biosdecode - BIOS information decoder

SYNOPSIS
       biosdecode [OPTIONS]

DESCRIPTION
       biosdecode  parses  the  BIOS memory and prints information about all structures (or entry points) it knows of.
```

Here is sample output from terminal:

```
$ sudo biosdecode
# biosdecode 2.12
ACPI 1.0 present.
    OEM Identifier: INTEL 
    RSD Table 32-bit Address: 0x3F6FD038
PNP BIOS 1.0 present.
    Event Notification: Not Supported
    Real Mode 16-bit Code Address: F000:B824
    Real Mode 16-bit Data Address: 0040:0000
    16-bit Protected Mode Code Address: 0x000FB82F
    16-bit Protected Mode Data Address: 0x00000400
    OEM Device Identifier: SST2400
SMBIOS 2.4 present.
    Structure Table Length: 1270 bytes
Structure Table Address: 0x000E44F0
Number Of Structures: 27
Maximum Structure Size: 152 bytes
```

Use **`sudo dmidecode`** for a more detailed output on **System Management BIOS** & **Desktop Management Interface**